# PostgreSQL - Get JSONB key/value pair inside object and return it

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This operator `?|` returns a boolean. It just checks to see if the string is contained in the string.

```
SELECT ids ?| '{100085,100087,100090,100091,100093,100095,100113,
100121,100126,100211,100213,100223,100324,100326}' 
FROM tableA

|ids|
{'100090':'123456789','100096':'987654321'}
```

Which will return true because id `100090` is in the ids jsonb column.

Question is, is there a way to return what it finds and not just a boolean. Instead of true, return the value of the match it finds e.g. return `'123456789'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, a bit complex, but at least functions and returns all values that are found with those keys. If you want just one then needs a limit:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT '{"100090":"123456789","100096":"987654321"}'::jsonb ->>
    unnest('{100085,100087,100090,100091,100093,100095,100113,100121,100126,100211,100213,100223,100324,100326}'::int[])::text AS result) AS x
  WHERE result IS NOT NULL;
```

Result:

```
  result
-----------
 123456789
(1 row)
```

Needs the subselect since for some reason trying to add the IS NOT NULL into the query otherwise just claims the column doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually never mind that last question, it works how I need it. thanks for this. I've been trying everything.  Instead of casting it as text can it be a bigint? I tried but then it comes as empty column.